# Find the most recent commits where two files were identical

Tags: git

I've got two files in a git repository, potentially on two different branches.  At some point in the history of their respective branches they had the same contents.  I'd like to find the most recent commits on each branch where the files were equal.

I could write a tool that would iterate the history of each commit and hash the file, then repeat on the other branch and find the best match.  Is there a better way built into git?

What if I want to do this with two sets of files, rather than a single file, and I don't know which pairs were identical previously?

Context: A project I work on pulled code from elsewhere at some point in the past and things have diverged now, including in file structure.  I'd like to generate a list of commits to consider pulling from upstream by finding commits that happened after the initial import of code and only affect files that were imported.

Comment: There should be. With some git internals. Not sure though, but I think the contents are already hashed and used as file names for blobs. If that is true and you can figure out a way to find (a) the hash you are looking for and (b) query git for all trees/commits which reference a given blob, you’re done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first cut at it, somebody might come up with something better

```
( git log --first-parent branch2..branch1 --pretty='%H 1'|cat -n  # branch1 commits and
  git log --first-parent branch1..branch2 --pretty='%H 2'|cat -n  # branch2 commits
) | while read l h b; do                 # append each commit's path/to/file's hash
            echo $l $h $b $(git rev-parse -q --verify $h:path/to/file); 
    done          |
    sort -s +3    |  # collect identical content together (key +3 is the hash)
    uniq -2       |  # keep only latest of each  per branch (key -2 is branch & hash
    uniq -D -3       # and only show content that appears on both branches
```

The key spec on sort is a deprecated form, I'm using it here to match `uniq`'s usage.

To find duplicates among sets of multiple files just do multiple echoes in the above, the idea stays the same.